# Cryptography and the kernel, System calls

Tags: linux-kernel, encryption, system-calls

Is cryptography implemented in user space or kernel space?

Are public/private key pairs generated in the kernel space?

What about encryption or decryption using a given public key or a given private key, or signing a file cryptographically?

Which system calls are used for these operations and how is the private key passed in/retrieved?

I've spent some time looking at the "Asymmetric Cipher Algorithm Definitions" page here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/crypto/api-akcipher.html
but I can't make heads or tails of what functions do what, and what the data structures in their parameters and returns are.

Simply put, which element of which structure corresponds to the private keys?

Comment: If someone could tell me why I'm losing points, I could change my approach to the community or modify my question to be more in line with community standards.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you found is mainly for kernel and library development. Cryptographic primitives are used in places such as the **IPSec** stack, that need to run in the kernel. As you can see in the [User Space Interface](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/crypto/userspace-if.html) chapter, public key cryptography is not accessible in userspace. Even if it were, you shouldn't be concerned, where the keys end up (hint: see those nice opaque `__ctx` members?). The interesting part is the functions that are provided.

If you are interested in cryptographic libraries on Linux, [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/), [GnuTLS](https://www.gnutls.org/) and [Libgcrypt](https://gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gcrypt/) are probably the most common choices. There is also a [comparison page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_cryptography_libraries) on Wikipedia. These run mostly in userspace and use the kernel Crypto API to improve performance.

**Edit**: if you really want to use the Crypto API, you can look on a per algorithm basis what those `__ctx` members contain. E.g. if you look at [rsa.c](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/crypto/rsa.c), you'll notice that the `__ctx` member of `crypto_akcipher` points to a `struct rsa_mpi_key` and you can get it with `rsa_get_key()`.

Comment: I'm interested in kernel development and malware analysis/RE so I thought it would be fun to write a toy Linux rootkit. I wanted to hook cryptography related system calls to harvest private and symmetric keys. I know there are probably easier ways to accomplish this in the user space, but I wanted to see how hooking system calls works and I thought that cryptography would be an interesting place to go. No, this isn't intended for production, I just want a resume builder and a little bit of kernel dev experience before I contribute to open source.

Comment: I added some details where to look for a key.

Comment: Once I get started on this project I'll see if I want to accept this answer. Another idea I had was to debug a crypto call down to where it hits the syscall level, which would be a better living example of what goes on than the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution would be to debug some code down to the syscall level to find where it interfaces with the kernel, since it seems as though the kernel reads from a buffer to perform crypto system calls.